# Using EF transaction across libraries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have this class A that begins an EF transaction where UserDb is my DbContext

```
 using (DbContextTransaction dbTransaction = UserDb.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
```

Then I have several inserts and there is a need to call another library [which essentially lives on the same server in the bin folder] to do another insert.

```
new ExtLibrary().CreatePoweruser(3, UserDb);
```

As you can see I am passing the same connection. And this statement is within the top using which I thought would mean that everythign is in the same transaction.

Extlibrary code:

> Data.Entities.User UserEntity = new Data.Entities.User            {
>
> ```
>             UserTypeId =34,
>
>             CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
>             CreatedBy = "mk92Test",
>                        };
>         UserDb.Users.Add(UserEntity);
>         UserDb.SaveChanges();
> ```

Everything works unless the ExtLibrary insert fails. Control comes back to the parent class which has rollback code on exception and I get an The underlying provider failed on rollback. But the first set of inserts certainly do rollback even after this exception.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you show your rollback code ?

Comment: Thanks, but I later realized that EF rolls back as soon as an exception is thrown and I was trying to explicitly call roll back, that caused the issue.